# How to find the max and min values of string rows of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

For each row of my data, I want to get the *min* and *max* values and
the *number of years* which are originally stored as a character. For example, consider the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4,
                 yr = c("1543,860,2023",
                        "2019,2018,2006,2007",
                        "1998,2012,2000,2020",
                        "2000"))
```

Output needed:

```
id                   yr  min_yr  max_yr  nYears
 1        1543,860,2023     860    2023       3
 2  2019,2018,2006,2007    2006    2019       4
 3  1998,2012,2000,2020    1998    2020       4
 4                 2000    2000    2000       1
```

Comment: (a) Do you want the `min` `max` values sorted by `numeric` or by `character`? (b) Do you have all the time 4 items in the column `yr`? (c) Do you also want a column that *counts the number of years*? Please could you *refine* your question. Thanks.

Comment: @GKi (a) By numbers, (b) No, it greatly varies, (c) Indeed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split the characters by `,`.
To iterate over the resulting list you can use `sapply`.
With `as.integer` the string is converted to an integer number. In this case maybe `as.numeric` would be an alternative, but as you have only years integer might be the better option.
With `range` you get the *min* and *max* values and with `length` the number of years.
`t` transposes the result that it can be used to add the columns *min_yr*, *max_yr* and *nYears* to the `data.frame` using `[<-`

```
df[c("min_yr", "max_yr", "nYears")] <-
  t(sapply(strsplit(df$yr, ","), \(x) c(range(as.integer(x)), length(x))))

df
#  id                  yr min_yr max_yr nYears
#1  1       1543,860,2023    860   2023      3
#2  2 2019,2018,2006,2007   2006   2019      4
#3  3 1998,2012,2000,2020   1998   2020      4
#4  4                2000   2000   2000      1

str(df)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ id    : int  1 2 3 4
# $ yr    : chr  "1543,860,2023" "2019,2018,2006,2007" "1998,2012,2000,2020" "2000"
# $ min_yr: int  860 2006 1998 2000
# $ max_yr: int  2023 2019 2020 2000
# $ nYears: int  3 4 4 1
```

Basically the same but not in one turn.

```
. <- lapply(strsplit(df$yr, ","), as.integer) #Split it by "," and convert it to integer
df$min_yr <- vapply(., min, integer(1)) #Get the minimum value
df$max_yr <- vapply(., max, integer(1)) #Get the minimum value
df$nYears <- lengths(.)
```

---

Benchmark only for *min* and *max* (original question).
@user2974951 fails due to sorting by character and @akrun expects same number of years.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(yr = replicate(1e5, paste(sample(0:2023, sample(1:100, 1)), collapse=",")))

library(stringr) #for Maël
library(dplyr)  #for Stefano Barbi and Maël
library(purrr)  #for Stefano Barbi

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
"Maël" = {df %>% 
            rowwise() %>% 
            mutate(min_yr = min(as.numeric(str_split_1(yr, ","))),
                   max_yr = max(as.numeric(str_split_1(yr, ","))))},
"Allan Cameron" = local({df[c('min_yr', 'max_yr')] <- t(sapply(df$yr, \(x) range(scan(text=x, sep = ',')))); df}),
"Stefano Barbi" = {mutate(df, strsplit(yr, ",") |>
                          map(as.numeric) |>
                          map(range) |>
                          map_dfr(setNames, c("min", "max")))},
user2974951 = local({df$min_yr=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$yr,","),min)))
  df$max_yr=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$yr,","),max)))
  df}),
#akrun = local({d1 <- read.csv(text = df$yr, header = FALSE) #Fails
#  df$min_yr <- do.call(pmin, d1)
#  df$max_yr <- do.call(pmax, d1)
#  df}),
GKi = local({df[c("min_yr", "max_yr")] <-
               t(sapply(strsplit(df$yr, ","), \(x) c(range(as.integer(x)))))
            df}),
GKi2 = local({. <- lapply(strsplit(df$yr, ","), as.integer)
  df$min_yr <- vapply(., min, integer(1))
  df$max_yr <- vapply(., max, integer(1))
  df})
)
```

Result

```
  expression       min median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
  <bch:expr>    <bch:> <bch:>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
1 Maël           6.23s  6.23s   0.161 242.7MB   4.66      1    29   6.23s <NULL>
2 Allan Cameron  3.74s  3.74s   0.267 867.4MB   6.69      1    25   3.74s <NULL>
3 Stefano Barbi  3.45s  3.45s   0.290 135.3MB   4.06      1    14   3.45s <NULL>
4 user2974951    2.59s  2.59s   0.387  88.9MB   0.387     1     1   2.59s <NULL>
5 GKi            1.44s  1.44s   0.694  95.8MB   1.39      1     2   1.44s <NULL>
6 GKi2           1.27s  1.27s   0.790  64.2MB   0.790     1     1   1.27s <NULL>
```

In this case GKi2 (doing it step by step) seems to be the best in respect of speed and memory consumption.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one-liner in base R that also works on any number.

```r
df[c('min_yr', 'max_yr')] <- t(sapply(df$yr, \(x) range(scan(text=x, sep = ','))))
```

Resulting in

```r
df
#>   id                  yr min_yr max_yr
#> 1  1 2000,2009,1999,2022   1999   2022
#> 2  2 2019,2018,2006,2007   2006   2019
#> 3  3 1998,2012,2000,2020   1998   2020
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df$min_yr=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$yr,","),min)))
df$max_yr=as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$yr,","),max)))

  id                  yr min_yr max_yr
1  1 2000,2009,1999,2022   1999   2022
2  2 2019,2018,2006,2007   2006   2019
3  3 1998,2012,2000,2020   1998   2020
```

Comment: Will this work also for years e.g. like `888`?

Comment: @GKi Probably not because it is comparing strings, but I don't think that will be an issue.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you so much. Just one final question: Is that possible to add a column that counts the number of years?

Answer (score 3):

using `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mutate(df, strsplit(yr, ",") |>
           map(as.numeric) |>
           map(range) |>
           map_dfr(setNames, c("min", "max")))

##>   id                  yr  min  max
##> 1  1 2000,2009,1999,2022 1999 2022
##> 2  2 2019,2018,2006,2007 2006 2019
##> 3  3 1998,2012,2000,2020 1998 2020
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `pmin/pmax` from `base R` - read the yr column with `read.csv` to create a data.frame and then use pmin/pmax

```
d1 <- read.csv(text = df$yr, header = FALSE)
df$min_yr <- do.call(pmin, d1)
df$max_yr <- do.call(pmax, d1)
```

-output

```
> df
  id                  yr min_yr max_yr
1  1 2000,2009,1999,2022   1999   2022
2  2 2019,2018,2006,2007   2006   2019
3  3 1998,2012,2000,2020   1998   2020
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(min_yr = min(as.numeric(str_split_1(yr, ","))),
         max_yr = max(as.numeric(str_split_1(yr, ","))))
 
     id yr                  min_yr max_yr
  <int> <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 2000,2009,1999,2022   1999   2022
2     2 2019,2018,2006,2007   2006   2019
3     3 1998,2012,2000,2020   1998   2020
```